# problem with checkbox in the payment

Tags: magento-1.8, payment

I have 3 payments methods activated on the store.

paypal, transfers and billet banking.

So, if the payment is made through transfers and billet banking, we have 10% discount. The rule is ok!

So, when I click the 1 time on the radio button of transfers or billet, the discount does not appear on the total, but, if I click before on paypal and after on the transfers or billet, the discount works.

So, what could it be? JS?

**My site:** `www.comerciomix.com.br`

Comment: luiza,it not work until the payment method set .On click  function did not payment method proper or you need update on the total by  ajax update

Comment: the onclick function is set on the method.phtml, right?

Comment: yes... you need to do this...

Comment: could I put here my method.phtml? Cause, this function is already set

Comment: screen shot payment step

Comment: so, it is not a static thing, I cant capture on a screenshot, if I click before on paypal and after on the transfers or billet, the discount works, but only if I click before in paypal checkbox.

Comment: https://youtu.be/EqtALLFYRCU  screencast, so you could see the issue

Comment: i was saw your screen shot.... but cannot  cart any product  due account  not created

Comment: there is no need to create account, neither I have an account

Comment: sorry, for mistake,i was click on wishlist buttom

Comment: There is no problem! :)

Comment: luiza,Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null at checkoutsimplificado.js:551 .you need to fixed it

Comment: thanks a lot, you know how could I fix it? Can I put here the entire checkoutsimplificado.js?